# Text Classification misclassifying?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification, binary-classification

I am trying to solve a binary classification problem. My labels are abusive (1) and non-abusive (0).
My dataset was imbalanced (more 1 than 0s) and I used oversampling of the minority label (i.e. 1) to balance my dataset. I have also done pre-processing, feature engineering using TF-IDF and then fed the dataset into a pipeline using 3 classification algorithms namely: Logistic Regression, SVM, and Decision Tree.

My evaluation metrics are:

```
    Logistic Regression:
[[376  33]
 [ 18  69]]
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.95      0.92      0.94       409
       1       0.68      0.79      0.73        87

accuracy                               0.90       496
macro avg          0.82      0.86      0.83       496
weighted avg       0.91      0.90      0.90       496
```

---

```
    SVM:
[[383  26]
 [ 23  64]]
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.94      0.94      0.94       409
       1       0.71      0.74      0.72        87

accuracy                               0.90       496
macro avg          0.83      0.84      0.83       496
weighted avg       0.90      0.90      0.90       496
```

---

```
    Decision Tree:
[[383  26]
 [ 28  59]]
          precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0       0.93      0.94      0.93       409
       1       0.69      0.68      0.69        87

accuracy                               0.89       496
macro avg          0.81      0.81      0.81       496
weighted avg       0.89      0.89      0.89       496
```

The issue I'm facing is that certain new abusive text is being predited as non-abusive. I think that I think my false positive (FP) and false-negative rate (FN) are too high and need to be reduced.
Do you have any suggestions on how to reduce FP and FN or any other suggestions to cater for my issue?
Thanks.

Comment: try to adjust decision thresholds and / or class weights when training. Sometimes oversampling is not the best solution to imbalanced problems

Comment: So I don't do oversampling and try to use class weights to check if it improves my algorithm. Do you know a technique or methodology to find an appropriate class weight for SVM?

Comment: Class weights are a type of hyper-parameters, any hyper-parameter search methodology can help

Comment: Ok thanks. GridSearchCV or RandomisedSearchCV. I will your solution and see if it improves the classification matrix.

Comment: I tried adjusting the hyper parameters for the algorithms but the same error i.e. abusive text is being classified as non-abusive.

Answer (score 0):

All 3 algorithms are giving very similar results. And looking at evaluation sample size I think training sample is not too large. It indicates me that if there is any opportunity, it's
a) in feature engineering
b) in not predicting for less confident cases
c) getting more data to train more complex algo

a) Feature Engineering - TFIDF or count vectorizer has a real world problem of having test words outside of training vocabulary. If you can use general language vocabulary for embedding both train and test sets, then results should improve. There are open source pretrained embeddings like USE, Glove etc. to do so.

b) Prediction Confidence - Along with class prediction you can also get probability of classification. Then check - below which cutoff of probability your F1 score gets too low. Don't predict for those low probability cases. Most practical systems accept limitation of AI.

c) More data will allow you to learn through more complex algorithms like boosting which may improve results. Hopefully you are already crossvalidating.

Also, based on the cost of error, you can decide whether FP or FN should be prioritized. Accordingly optimize precision/ recall.

Comment: My sample size is small (3000 records). For (a), it will impossible to use pre-trained embedding since I'm doing it for a non-English language. For (c), time constraints do not permit me to gather more data and label them. Could you elaborate on (b)? (I tried some googling but in vain). I appreciate the time you took to help me.

Comment: Regarding a) I know that there are multilingual pretrained models (example [link](https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-multilingual-large/3)) although I have only used English.

Comment: Regarding b) You can get the probability that a new text belongs to each class 0/1 (python sklearn 'predict_proba()'). Some algorithms like logistic regression actually calculate these probabilities and then classifies based on the probability. Some algorithms estimate these probabilities separately. In any case, for each text you can take the max of probability out of class 0 and 1. That is the confidence of prediction. Now you need to check below which probability cutoff you are mostly getting misclassification. Those are your low confidence prediction where you shouldn't predict.